# How to schedule task (or jobs) to run in background and under user impersonation

Tags: c#, sql-server, scheduled-tasks, background-process

I have this scenario where I need users to be able to log on to a machine and schedule some task (like running a query and getting results and saving them) for future run.

Let me cite an example. For example, I have a service. A user (User1) (who is a domain user), connects to this service and send a SQL query, server name and database name to my service call). What this service needs to do here is create a task which will run at some future time in the day (may be in the night i.e.: 11 PM). This task when runs the query at 11 PM will connect to the SQL on the Server name and database name passed earlier and fire the query and then save the results in excel. The query when runs should use the user (User1) context so that if there are any restricted permissions should honor that. The same is needed if I use a MDX query.

The server on which this service is deployed, is a domain joined machine. The service works on Network Service currently and I can see the calling user. I do not want to add all users as administrator in the server.

I tried creating a Scheduled tasks dynamically, I am able to do that successfully after giving access to Local Policy (Log on as Batch Service) and access to folders under C:\Windows\system32\tasks to a group (Created for this type of users, all users are part of this group). The option "When running tasks, use the following user account" it is getting set to the caller user (User1), but I am not able to set option "Run whether user is logged on or not". This option is needed because when I need to fire the query it should work under User1 and user1 will never log on to the machine.

Any suggestions would be helpful. I am also open to ideas of not going the Scheduled tasks approach if any other approach is better suited for my kind of requirement.

Thanks.
Girija Shankar Beuria

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a stored procedure that does the task(s) you want done. Within the SP, you can EXECUTE AS which ever login/user you want. Use SQL Agent to schedule the task. These are all easy to do and SQL Server books online has detailed information and examples so just look it up there.

Btw, I'm assuming you're DBA on the instance hence you have permissions to run EXECUTE AS on any login/user.

Comment: SQLmojoe, Thanks for looking at my issue. But my problem would be that how would it then : 1. Query MDX 2. Query Tabular 3. Save the results in excel. Also I would like to query some services to get data and save in excel. The sources for me would be different for each job depending on user preference for data (like SQL Database, SSAS cube, Tabular, Rest service, WCF service etc.).  Sorry for not mentioning that earlier. I guess that would be difficult to do if I try your approach. - Girija